# Flutter 3D Cube rotation Transform Matrix (Like Instagram stories)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a PageView.builder and I am trying to add a custom transition effect just like Instagram's stories. [Swift Package which has a gif showing the desired effect](https://github.com/oyvinddd/ohcubeview) Using matrix4 is hard to debug and require lots of math I guess so right now I am getting Gaps and Overlaps between the Left and Right child of the PageView.

[image: My current Implementation as you can see is far from perfect]

The code is taken partially from the tutorial at: [custom pageview transitions](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded)

```
PageView.builder(
  controller: controller,
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    if (position == currentPageValue.floor()) {
        //page being swiped from
        return Transform(
            transform: _matrix3dSwipeL(position),   //First Matrix ???
            child: _child,
        );
    } else if (position == currentAnimationValue.floor() + 1){
        //page being swiped to 
        return Transform(
            transform: _matrix3dSwipeR(position),   //Second Matrix ???
            child: _child,
        );         
    } else {
        //off screen page
        return _child;
    }
  },
  itemCount: 10,
)
```

The Matrix I came up with right now is(does not work!):

```
Matrix4 _matrix3dSwipeL(int index) {
    double _animationvalue =
        ui.lerpDouble(0.0, math.pi / 2, _currentPageValue - index);
    return Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
      ..translate(((_screenSize.width / 2) * math.sin(_animationvalue)), 0.0,
          ((_screenSize.width / 2) * math.sin(_animationvalue)))
      ..rotateY(_animationvalue);
  }

  Matrix4 _matrix3dSwipeR(int index) {
    double _animationvalue =
        ui.lerpDouble(0.0, math.pi / 2, _currentPageValue + 1 - index);
    return Matrix4.identity()
      ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
      ..translate(((-_screenSize.width / 2) * math.cos(_animationvalue)), 0.0,
          ((_screenSize.width / 2) * math.cos(_animationvalue)))
      ..rotateY(-(math.pi / 2) + _animationvalue);
  }
```

How would we construct the two Transformations for the current and the next page?

Comment: are you still interested on this ? I'm finishing a flutter package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just released a package that has the animation you want. It's called `cube_transition`.

You can check it : https://pub.dev/packages/cube_transition

Using my package the code is very simple.

```dart
import 'package:cube_transition/cube_transition.dart';

const places = [ ...];

class Sample2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PageView Cube Transition'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: height,
          child: CubePageView(
            children: places
                .map(
                  (item) =>  Image.network(
                        item.url,
                        height: height,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Hi @diegodeveloper - love your package! Is there any way that you can preload the pages in the cubepageview? (e.g. with allowimplicitscrolling = true)

Comment: hmm you can open a new issue on the github repo

Comment: Hi diego - I fixed it by adding 'allowimplicitscrolling = true' in your source code (in the pageview.builder widget. Thanks a lot for the great package!

Comment: maybe you could send a PR